# kill command doesn't work in awk

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, awk

There is a unix shell command,like this:

```
lsof -i:8888 | awk ' $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print $2;kill -9 $2 } '
```

it can print the pid I want to kill correctly,but the `kill` command doesn't kill the process of this pid,but if I run it separtely it will work,that is:
at first,run

```
lsof -i:8888 | awk ' $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print $2} '
```

to find the pid I want to kill
then,run

```
kill <pid>#pid is get from last command
```

then the process will be killed correctly,

I'm running on mac,anyone can tell me why this happens and how to solve it,thanks!

Comment: Your awk only outputs the kill command without asking the shell to execute it. You can ask the shell to execute a string with `$(string)`, like @iamauser wrote.

Comment: @WalterA,but only pid outputted with my shell command.no kill command printed.

Comment: You are right, I thought about `print "kill -9 " $2`.

Comment: Would you expect to be able to call the shell's `kill` command directly from a C program? No, of course not. Awk is not shell, it's a completely different tool with it's own language, just like C is. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `kill` command in `awk`, you need to use a different approach, the simpler being calling the shell `kill` command.

Here is one possible still not optimal way to do it, should you really want to do it from inside `awk`:

```
lsof -i:8888 | awk '
    $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {
        print $2
        command=sprintf("kill -9 %d",$2)
        system(command)
        close(command)
} '
```

Note 1: Answering to the comment *only commands that awk supports can be executed,and others will be ignored?*

Yes, as a side effect of the way `awk` process its instructions, most other "commands" might indeed be ignored in `awk` if there are used with the shell syntax like you did. Using the awk syntax `kill(-9,$2)` would have triggered an error but `kill -9 $2` does not.
Probably all `awk` implementations do not consider an undefined token as a syntax error. They just convert it to its value as a variable, here an empty string or 0, and concatenate the arguments to it, if any. There are cases when this can lead to an error, like when an `awk` builtin command appears in the arguments, where the command name has a suffix introduced by a dot (e.g. command.sh) making it an invalid variable name, or if a full path is given, which might trigger puzzling error messages like in the following test:

This awk script:

```
BEGIN {
    /usr/bin/kill -9 9999
}
```

will result in these messages, depending on the `awk` implementation used:

Legacy awk (the original old implementation)

```
awk: syntax error near line 2
awk: illegal statement near line 2
```

Standard awk (a.k.a. nawk)

```
nawk: division by zero
 source line number 2
```

GNU awk (a.k.a. gawk)

```
gawk: test:2: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Mike's awk (a.k.a. mawk)

```
* No error reported, no output
```

Busybox awk

```
awk: test:2: Division by zero
```

Note 2: In your case, while it would just work, there is no much point using the method I describe which would be overkill. That's why I wrote "*should you really want to do it from inside awk*".

However, there are certainly more complex cases where `system()` would be very useful with `awk`, albeit inherently dangerous, just like it is with several other programming languages.

Comment: Meaning that in '{}' of awk,only commands that awk supports can be executed,and others will be ignored?

Comment: Precisely. Awk is a different scripting language with its own syntax and set of commands.

Comment: Hardly "Precisely" - other commands will NOT be ignored, they just won't do what you want. So this answer shows HOW to do what you are asking for but of course you should NEVER actually do it. shell is a tool for manipulating files and processes and sequence calls to tools. awk is a tool for manipulating text. You are trying to manipulate (kill) a process so that is a job for shell, not for awk. Just do `shell {awk; kill}` as shown in all of the other answers, not `shell { awk { shell { kill } } }` as shown in this one.

Comment: @EdMorton Actually, other "commands" will be ignored under awk when used like the OP did, see my updated answer. I also commented about `system` usage.

Comment: Try executing `awk 'BEGIN{foo.sh}'` and you'll get something like `awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{foo.sh}\nawk: cmd. line:1:          ^ syntax error`. awk ignores nothing, it just tries to guess what you meant and the only thing guaranteed as that it'll almost certainly get it wrong

Comment: @EdMorton Unix commands generally have no extension, and I explicitly referred about tokens. Anyway, answer updated to make clearer why arbitrary strings are usually ignored by `awk`. This behavior is quite specific to `awk` and probably confused the OP in the first place by failing to output any error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
kill $(lsof -i:8888 | awk ' $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $2}')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,it works well,but can you explain why my shell command doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof -i:8888 | awk ' $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print $2} ' | xargs kill
```

when `kill` is written inside awk '{}' it will not be executed on shell instead it is taken by awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof -i:8888 | awk ' $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print $2 } ' | xargs kill -9
```

To execute the awk output as part of the command you need to pipe the awk output to xargs command.

Comment: Simple that just works as piping `| xargs kill -9`

Answer (score 0):

This construct works on MacOS (and Linux)

```
lsof -i:8888 | awk ' $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print $2; "/bin/kill -9 " $2 | getline resp } '
```

since the string before the `| getline` is interpreted as a command.